# Type inference from synchronous or asynchronous parameters

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise, type-inference

I want to define an "execute" method which returns a synchronous or an asynchronous result depending on its parameters:

```
type Callback = (...args: Arguments) => Result
const result: Result = execute(callback: Callback, args: Arguments)
```

```
type Callback = (...args: Arguments) => Promise<Result>
const result: Promise<Result> = execute(callback: Callback, args: Arguments)
```

```
type Callback = (...args: Arguments) => Result | Promise<Result>
const result: Promise<Result> = execute(callback: Callback, args: Promise<Arguments>)
```

I try this with no success:

[sample code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ssl=30&ssc=73&pln=30&pc=85#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAKGwFwE8AHWAAgGFlpoAjZYAawB4BBVAcwFcBbWMPCKVgAPPHwAmgtqmQEmyMAQB8AGlIAlWBE7Q8S0gF5sAH1Lp08S2nYQAXKTZde-CJkP7N23TlPnL8azsHDh4%20ATcDfQAFVBBuAEsIWCZPHT0cbFBIPCFhWGBOMUNSVhDnAVyxMElgmTkFZTVU3X10YCpaegZ7Smo6RlKnMIgmrTTVUkD7R1CXUlMYuMTkmfKIJUx7QhIQADNJjkERKprFhKTB2YF9AH5SM%20WUsZbSe008TlQwABViZO3YHtSO0%20l19JFSABvbCkUjxfboQJw7IKYCA-YPJJuaGw2GoWAfL4HGzwPAACz46HxUGgADdYOIAPpIiE43GwrIQHLUtLFEGdRgWSzUmD0pmBHDsvEEz5gUg83Qw3EAX0luIA9Or5TKiYjDqSKWAqVpRQzmYd3MCOv0GEL4CK6WaJW5kIJOGAGGAQAB3MAuwSY5LNPRK5W4WGwaBJKFK6WEuX8m128xIm53ADaAF1-cEhi5MGqw2HMuAuZMIAQwMBGeJYNwQMVXZXgGZaVROLB7GAeDRYKgIvo2ZycshG97kPEcoH7SbHegAIxq-HxyakADUpDb0A72GLw9IFarNbrDYMrfbndI3e4vf7lvn683F-wf1IAGVmwARE-B4rvWW-CQTAAkCh7VrW9ZKLg%204KngjLzl2PZ9sUIj5IUsDoGBx71mo6bztmJbZNqXhwQATPYgZMNet7grkaFiJhzbYSAajTg69LoHhmblqQ6bUX22Y4DBzxwQAzBRsTnMk-GoLRqEFAxTZHhBLG8fhQmltyImMgALBJSwXDJcl5ApGFKeBJ64epQA)

```
console.clear()

type Callback<Arguments extends Array<any>, Result> =
| ((...args: Arguments) => Result)
| ((...args: Arguments) => Promise<Result>)

const execute = <Arguments extends Array<any>, Result> (callback: Callback<Arguments, Result>, args: Arguments | Promise<Arguments>): typeof args extends Promise<Arguments> ? Promise<Result> : ReturnType<typeof callback> => {
  if (args instanceof Promise) {
    return args.then(resolved_args => {
      const result = callback(...resolved_args)
      return result
    })
  }

  else {
    return callback(...((args ?? []) as Arguments))
  }
}

const async_demo = async (value: number) => {
  const a = await Promise.resolve(1)
  return a + value
}

const sync_demo = (value: number) => 1 + value
type SyncDemoResult = ReturnType<typeof sync_demo>

const result_1: number = execute(sync_demo, [1])
const result_2: Promise<number> = execute(sync_demo, Promise.resolve([1] as [number]))
const result_3: Promise<number> = execute(async_demo, [1])
const result_4: Promise<number> = execute(async_demo, [1])
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't know TypeScript well enough to know if it's possible, but is it desirable even if it's possibl?.  A function that is sometimes synchronous and sometimes asynchronous is just not a good idea and certainly requires you perverting type safety in TypeScript to even attempt it.  I would suggest `executeAsync()` for your asynchronous operations.

Comment: with this technique, I can share business code between client code (synchrone) and server (asynchrone) where data access (repository in DDD) are sync or async. by injecting repository with "execute", I can get methods which are sync on the client, and async on the server. Promises cost too much in performance, and are sometimes more complex with hooks in React applications.

Comment: But, if your code is just branching underneath the API and above the API to handle asynchronous and synchronous cases and you're just stuffing everything through a non-typed and non-descriptive single API, I don't see what you're gaining.  You can still share just as much code if you split it according to synchronous and asynchronous.  I think you're perverting the design and use of the API in the interest of perfect code sharing.  IMO, that's the wrong way to prioritize.  Cleanliness of design, use and maintenance should be prioritized first.

Comment: the magic comes with functional programming: the "execute" method is currified and is used to wrap repository access: so I can create business methods which are shared between client (sync / store) and server (async / database). I inject repository access method to build client or server code. same code, 2 signatures depending of the injected methods. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Below defined two overloads: first accepts direct callback arguments, second - promise resolving callback arguments:

```
type AnyFunc = (...args: any[]) => any;

function execute<T extends AnyFunc>(callback: T, args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>
function execute<T extends AnyFunc>(callback: T, args: Promise<Parameters<T>>): Promise<ReturnType<T>>
function execute<T extends AnyFunc>(callback: T, args: Parameters<T> | Promise<Parameters<T>>) {
  if (args instanceof Promise) {
    return args.then(resolved_args => {
      const result = callback(...resolved_args)
      return result
    })
  }
  return callback(...args);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAYgVzgYygXigCgHQECGATgOYDOAXFIQgNoC6AlFgHw0IDcAUNwGao0wAJYB7OFAgAPCGmTAIAHgAqkqQrgATcrAQp0rHGkIAbEwCNCaANbVlAGhpkqUAAolCAWwgLi5FaxM1ABKPsjEcMrgSsqs-IIi4mqy8jFqGtq6SIKGxmaWNnaOJBTUrsSinsLkSu7EXj4QfgGBZRVVNYqhwOGR0S3x6IkS0ikKKukQWjrw2QZGphZWtlAOTqVuHt6%20-rFQAD5u7dW1W43NsYFQAN7cUFDCfLglOsJw5MC0aBCiT%20WVJxYt3u92IYQi63IeGAAAspjgweRRCYAG4QTQAfRebBudxB9zQ4g%20UERyBMwCwUDySxs%20AIiORaMxLyYePxYJ6ENJ5LZUAAvqz7ny8RzelTFgVrHS8CyeMLuIT3hTCOQQOgMZoIJ5RJSVWqMDgUaZkBBqHBkJ5zE0WJh2MCqUTlbqAO6EYQU-4dCB4BmoiA4ACMgpJ4IkhCgAGooEaTCbuPLFcTVerNdrKYbjaaoObLdacQHI9HM9xQJAoABlfUAES1olC5DJFOw3V6UUgilLPyeybQGtrcQVjpDDfJGIDZotVuIlNGcgUOB7fe1jjoAeYg6Vw8bGIATG0AZ0c1P2NhZ6kF-ql6JHJ6Tj6IEi-ThVwwaDo6EemsxWYmKdzgBiADM%205eoon7ECeyRzv6eoprWK5rj%20Q7-hiAAsIEnGBk5NJBZ7zrBvapteUAvkwQA)

Comment: thanks a lot ! I just add a case to do all things I want

Answer (score 0):

With the solution of @aleksey-l, this is the solution I will use to share the same code with asynchronous or synchronous inputs:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAYgVzgYygXigCgHQECGATgOYDOAXFIQgNoC6AlFgHw0IDcAUKJLAhjkQ6FOgA8AFXbZ8RMlQ4hGLTOwAKxAPYBbAJbkIU1j24AzVGmB6tcKBAAeENMmBGAqgBook%20w7dwACbkAiBCImhiaOLurKw4aIQANkkARoRoANbUkt4kFNSaugZG6iSEOhBuxOTGrEyF2vqGMazmlta2fs6uRr6OAcGhUfGJKelZOXkKheWV1bXSDVAASlXIxHCS4H1tFuiddo49blJ%20gyHwSJajyWkZ2T7TBVBFzaVzVRA1dctvJeI1sANlsdnV2gcbEcnC5Tv1-BAgpcECMEncJo9cjQZq9PgtjFAAD6vJoAsrECpfH7SepQADe3CgUD0Zlw%20RCejg5GAtDQEC0rP%20hhYDKZTOI6022IoeGAAAtETgJeQtEkAG4QQIAfXZbCgY3uWTkeGVqo12vZTCYjKgAF8bRLgVKDRjjZaePbuAB6L1QAC0AcDQeDIdDYfDwe43DQtm5NGE6C1gQgOi0WHjEVwauSyAg1DgyB0qW%20qnYov1seANHThAA7oQ9FWhRATRAVeqIDgAIzW8WSuyEKAAaig2aSue4np9-ojs7n88DUZjXKrCbQSZTadkY9z%20cLxeIpagXeHo5zECj04X15vkejlagyuQSWAWq7e6L33Tx1hnbXG9Tbw6C7Zh7xXR822fV8ACZGmKFoC0-YgZG6X8cH-ZNAJJeCW1NDscGAhh4ygOhEIPZhrWXOMnxfLUAGY4PecQyO%20FCf16HBCAwzcgJAyiHxo18ABZGIBFjkO-GEOK4iIAK0bxm1bdsNQIkDiNI-dvgooA)

```js
type AnyFunc = (...args: any[]) => any;
type AnyAsyncFunc<T> = (...args: any[]) => Promise<T>;

function execute<U, T extends AnyAsyncFunc<U>>(callback: T, args: Promise<Parameters<T>>): Promise<U>
function execute<T extends AnyFunc>(callback: T, args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T>
function execute<T extends AnyFunc>(callback: T, args: Promise<Parameters<T>>): Promise<ReturnType<T>>
function execute<T extends AnyFunc>(callback: T, args: Parameters<T> | Promise<Parameters<T>>) {
  if (args instanceof Promise) {
    return args.then(resolved_args => callback(...resolved_args))
  }
  return callback(...args);
}

// --------------------------------------------------

const async_demo = async (value: number) => {
  const a = await Promise.resolve(1)
  return a + value
}

// --------------------------------------------------

const sync_demo = (value: number) => 1 + value

// --------------------------------------------------

const result_1: number = execute(sync_demo, [1])
const result_2: Promise<number> = execute(sync_demo, Promise.resolve([1] as [number]))
const result_3: Promise<number> = execute(async_demo, [1])
const result_4: Promise<number> = execute(async_demo, Promise.resolve([1] as [number]))
```

Comment: `AnyAsyncFunc` is redundant because it is already covered by `AnyFunc` and `ReturnType` will handle this properly

Comment: @aleksey-l: no, without it, the returned type are Promise<Promise<U>>; any idea to solve that in another way?

Comment: You could use something like `type UnpackPromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer R> ? R : T;` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiAYgVzgYygXigCgHQECGATgOYDOAXFIQgNoC6AlFgHw0IDcAUN6JFACqcMITQBrAArEA9gFsAluQgAeACrtsaqBAAewCHAAm5KNPlLVCuADMIxKACV2AfidRqantyMQ0AGxJoG1Q0YAUZOB1dP2QDdWiDY1N4JFDWHDRCf38AIzFxTwAaGjIqMxJCOQgDYnJ1ViZqRxrkYjg1cFUNHz9A4mDQ8Mjo2PjtPSSTWAQUdAysnPyJYtKKanNFZRVJSura+o1Gjdkt1WFRCU3LFRbgNo6uhtZWXl8AoKgQ9GGownIQOgAPq+OQyHAAN2yyAg1DgyDkuXsTTMpxu8MR9le3DQkXIwCgA3IyH8wCBACYsKM0HEIDh-oC0CCIGCStdlHgiTJ-BC6XQAIwMGimOgYpHEZhMThAA